# How to connect to hive installed on an ec2 instance from aws glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hive, pyspark, aws-glue

I want to access hive metastore by running a spark job on AWS Glue. Doing so requires me to put the hive's instance's ip and access it. From my local, it works but not from AWS Glue.

I have tried to access Hive using the following piece of code:

```
spark_session = (
    glueContext.spark_session
    .builder
    .appName('example-pyspark-read-and-write-from-hive')
    .config(
        "hive.metastore.uris",
        "thrift://172.16.12.34:9083",
        conf=SparkConf()
    )
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
)
```

I have also looked at various documentations but none could tell my how to connect to an ec2 instance at a specific port.

The code is:

```
import sys

from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import (DataFrameReader, DataFrameWriter, HiveContext,
                         SparkSession)

"""
SparkSession ss = SparkSession
.builder()
.appName(" Hive example")
.config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://localhost:9083")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate();
"""
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark_session = (
    glueContext.spark_session
    .builder
    .appName('example-pyspark-read-and-write-from-hive')
    .config(
        "hive.metastore.uris",
        "thrift://172.16.12.34:9083",
        conf=SparkConf()
    )
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
)
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
data = [('First', 1), ('Second', 2), ('Third', 3), ('Fourth', 4), ('Fifth', 5)]
df = spark_session.createDataFrame(data)
df.write.saveAsTable('example_2')
job.commit()
```

I expect to get the table written in Hive but instead I get the following error from Glue:

```
An error occurred while calling o239.saveAsTable. No Route to Host from ip-172-31-14-64/172.31.14.64 to ip-172-31-15-11.ap-south-1.compute.internal:8020 failed on socket timeout exception: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host;
```

Comment: Hey! I am not sure if this will work but, if your hive metastore is in a private subnet, you can try and create a dummy "Glue connection" with the network information of the EC2 instance and attach it to the job. This should ideally create a private route between the backend resources used by Glue to your EC2 instance.

Comment: What should be the connection type while creating the connection?

Comment: JDBC connection with a random connection string, or maybe a string  conforming with the EC2 instance